# Drupal 7 on Windows - File Module Problems

Tags: sql-server, iis, drupal

Installed Drupal 7 using the Web Platform installer on Windows 2008

For some reason, the file module, when you upload a file, uses the first
few letters of the filename as the unique key to store in the database, which of course causes problems very fast.

I'm wondering does anybody have a workaround for this?

```
An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally. Debugging information follows. 

Path: /file/ajax/field_file/und/0/form-EBMatHzV5cZXcWvXJtdADSdyw7Id9-GIpFM_NCJg_a4 

StatusText: n/a 

ResponseText:  Error message PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client10.0][SQL Server]Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.file_managed' with unique index 'uri_unique'. in drupal_write_record() (line 6776 of  ..........\includes\common.inc). Error The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.   

ReadyState: undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced exactly the same problem today. It happened when I was trying to load a new theme.

I have installed another instance of Drupal with a MySQL database to compare the tables and check if there were a calculated field there.

There was none. In MySQL the index is built on the field 'uri'

So, in my SQL server database,  I moved the 'uri_unique' index from the field '__unique_uri' to the field 'uri' (like in MySQL). And it worked just fine !

I assume it's less efficient as the field is nvarchar(255) where the calculated field was a varbinary(16)... and I hope i won't be in trouble later...But at least, it solved the problem.

Comment: Similar to the solution I found where I changed the calculated field, but I think your solution might even work better. Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

I just found the bug report for that problem: 
http://drupal.org/node/10508004
(There is a patch)

Comment: This issues seems to be missing now?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently some genious inserted this in the database:

the __unique_uri in the file_managed table is a calculated field:

```
(CONVERT([varbinary](16),hashbytes('MD4',coalesce(CONVERT([varbinary],[uri],0),CONVERT([varbinary],[__pk],0))),0))
```